# Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with click logic

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use click option to make a call to URL but getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, can you guys tell what is wrong in this code?

Looks like I have not placed myChartG1.click logic at the correct block, I got this code from one of the post on stack website but it doesn't seem to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <title>My Chart.js Chart</title>
    <style>
        div.container2 {
            width: 80%;
        }
        
        </head><body>

    </style>
    <div class="container2">
        <canvas id="myChartG1"></canvas>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="USERJSINJECTION1" value="" />
    <canvas id="myChartG1" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
    <script>
        console.log(Chart.defaults.global)

        var obj = JSON.parse('%Bind(:1)');
        //

        //
        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.Account.JAN.FY + "," + obj.Account.JAN.Month;
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChartG1").getContext('2d');
        var myChartG1 = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [obj.Account.JAN.Month, obj.Account.FEB.Month, obj.Account.MAR.Month, obj.Account.APR.Month, obj.Account.MAY.Month, obj.Account.JUN.Month, obj.Account.JUL.Month, obj.Account.AUG.Month, obj.Account.SEP.Month, obj.Account.OCT.Month, obj.Account.NOV.Month, obj.Account.DEC.Month],
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Monthly Budget',
                        data: [obj.Account.JAN.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.FEB.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.MAR.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.APR.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.MAY.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.JUN.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.JUL.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.AUG.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.SEP.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.OCT.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.NOV.MonthlyBudget,
                            obj.Account.DEC.MonthlyBudget
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,0.4)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Monthly Posted',
                        data: [obj.Account.JAN.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.FEB.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.MAR.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.APR.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.MAY.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.JUN.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.JUL.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.AUG.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.SEP.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.OCT.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.NOV.MonthlyPosted,
                            obj.Account.DEC.MonthlyPosted
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,0.4)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Monthly Variance',
                        data: [obj.Account.JAN.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.FEB.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.MAR.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.APR.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.MAY.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.JUN.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.JUL.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.AUG.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.SEP.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.OCT.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.NOV.MonthlyVariance,
                            obj.Account.DEC.MonthlyVariance
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,0.4)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }, {
                        label: 'YTD Budget',
                        data: [obj.Account.JAN.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.FEB.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.MAR.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.APR.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.MAY.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.JUN.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.JUL.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.AUG.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.SEP.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.OCT.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.NOV.YTDBudget,
                            obj.Account.DEC.YTDBudget
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,0.4)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'YTD Posted',
                        data: [obj.Account.JAN.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.FEB.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.MAR.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.APR.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.MAY.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.JUN.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.JUL.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.AUG.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.SEP.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.OCT.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.NOV.YTDPosted,
                            obj.Account.DEC.YTDPosted
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,0.4)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'YTD Variance',
                        data: [obj.Account.JAN.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.FEB.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.MAR.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.APR.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.MAY.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.JUN.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.JUL.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.AUG.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.SEP.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.OCT.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.NOV.YTDVariance,
                            obj.Account.DEC.YTDVariance
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,0.4)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Annual Variance',
                        data: [obj.Account.JAN.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.FEB.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.MAR.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.APR.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.MAY.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.JUN.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.JUL.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.AUG.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.SEP.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.OCT.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.NOV.AnnualVariance,
                            obj.Account.DEC.AnnualVariance
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 0.4)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,0.4)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(0, 255, 153, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 204, 0, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 102, 255,1)'

                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                ]
            },
    
            options: {
                layout: {
                    padding: {
                        left: 50,
                        right: 20,
                        top: 0,
                        bottom: 0
                    }
                },
                //animation: false,
                //events: ['click'],
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: "right",
                    // labels: { fontColor: 'rgb(0, 255, 153)'} change legend font color
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: true,
                responsive: true,
                responsiveAnimationDuration: 1500,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                                    return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                                } else {
                                    return '$' + value;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                },
                tootltips: {
                    tooltipTemplate: "<%= addCommas(value) %>"
                }
            }
                    $("#myChartG1").click(
                function(evt) {
                    var activePoints = myChartG1.getSegmentsAtEvent(evt);
                    var url = "http://example.com/?label=" + activePoints[0].label + "&value=" + activePoints[0].value;
                    alert(url);
                }
            );
            
        });

    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you open your console? Where is the error? Did you check your code before coming here (it's most likely a typo).

Comment: The error I pasted here is from the console, there are no typos